# How to show nested array data in vuejs component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm running the following query:
`$users=User::with('roles.permissions')->get()->unique();`

this query returns result set:

```
Array = [
{
    created_at: "2019-01-11 09:27:02",
    deleted_at: null,
    email: "admin@example.com",
    email_verified_at: null,
    id: 1,
    name: "ADMIN",
    roles: [
        {id: 1, name: "Admin", slug: "Admin", description: "This is Super-Admin Role", created_at: "2019-01-11 09:27:02",
      permissions: [
       {id:1, name:"Create,slug:"Create"},
       {id:1, name:"Read",slug:"Read"},
       {id:1, name:"Delete",slug:"Delete"},
],
},

    ],
},

]
```

returns user details with `roles` I want to show this result set in my `Vue Component` table.

this my `vue component` read `method`

```
  read:function(){
        axios.get('/userlist')
        .then(response=>{
            console.log(response.data);

        })

    }
```

This is my table

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>no.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
    <th>Roles</th>
    <th>Permissions</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(user,key) in users">
      <td>{{++key}}</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

> How to show user,roles and permissions separately in html table.

Comment: Please, show us your table's html code.

Comment: `<table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                    <th>no.</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th>Roles</th>
                    <th>Permissions</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(user,key) in users">
                        <td>{{++key}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>`

Comment: Be sure to edit your post and put your code there instead of in a comment, Gabrielle.

Comment: I already edited. @WildBeard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your API result in your component `data`. But you need to prepare your component data to receive your users.

```
data() {
  return {
     users: []
  }
}
```

Now, you should make your function update this brand new data.

```
read:function(){
    axios.get('/userlist')
    .then(response=>{
        this.users = response.data;
    })

}
```

Now, I assume that you want to display user's roles as a concatenated string. Then, you need a function to do this.

```
methods: {
    getRoles: function(roles) {
        let rolesString = ''

        roles.forEach((role, index) => {
            if (index != 0)
                rolesString += ', '
            rolesString = rolesString + role.name
        })
        return rolesString
    },
    getPermissionsFromRoles: function(roles) {
        let permissionsList = []

        roles.permissions.forEach((permission) => {
            if (permissionsList.indexOf(permission.name) != -1) {
                permissionsList.push(permission.name)
            }
        })
        let permissionsString = ''
        if (permissionsList.length > 0) {
            permissionsList.forEach((permission, index) => {
                if (index != 0)
                    permissionsString += ', '
                permissionsString += permission
            })
        }
        return permissionsString
    }
}
```

Then, you can use this function in your template to handle your user roles.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>no.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
    <th>Roles</th>
    <th>Permissions</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(user,key) in users">
      <td>{{key}}</td>
      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
      <td>{{user.email}}</td>
      <td>{{getRoles(user.roles)}}</td>
      <td>{{getPermissionsFromRoles(user.roles)}}</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to get the role name. Try again, please. `rolesString = rolesString + role.name`

Comment: `<td>{{getPermissions(user.roles.permissions)}}</td>` I've tried this. and write the `getPermissions()` as like `getRoles()` but it's shows `TypeError`.

Comment: You didn't send your permission data, could you edit your post, please?

Answer (score 0):

rendering in the template will look like:

`<td v-for="role in roles">{{role}}</td>`

you will also need to have roles in your data:

```
data() {
  return {
     roles: []
  }
}
```

and finally make your function update the data

```
function(){
   .then(response=>{
      this.roles = response.data
        })

}
```